# quiero requerir campos si estan vacios en laravel pero no me funciona si lo hago con ajax y button type submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

El problema que tengo es que si lo hago con un span ahi si me envia los datos pero me deja de funcionar el required pero si lo cambio por un button de tipo submit ahi si me funciona pero me tira un error 
este es el error que me tira una vez le doy click para enviar los datos cuando tengo los campos llenos

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message

```
 <div class="modal-body mx-6">
                    {{Form::open(array( 'url'=>'#','id'=>'formulario','method'=>'post'))}}
                    <h1>Registrar<span class="badge badge-secondary">Gerencias</span></h1>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('codigo', 'Codigo:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            {!! Form::text('codigo', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control','maxlength'=>'2', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el Codigo','required'=> 'true']) !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('ga', 'Gerencia administrativa:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            {!! Form::text('ga', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Nombre dela Gerencia']) !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">

                    <span  class="btn btn-success" onclick="submit()" id="enviar">GUARDAR</span>

    //si lo hago de esta forma con el button si me tira el msj de requerir el campo pero ala hora de llenarlo y enviarlo me tira el error

                    {{--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="submit()" id="enviar">GUARDAR</button>--}}




                </div>
                {{Form::close()}}
                <div id="resultado"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>




<script>
    function submit () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            header:$('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        });

        $('#enviar').attr("disabled","disabled");
        var url = 'gerencia.crear';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $('#formulario').serialize(),
            dataType:'html',

            success: function (data) {
                var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if ((obj.estado=='ok')){
                    alert(obj.mensaje);
                    window.location="{{ route('gerencia_inicio') }}"

                } else{
                    alert(obj.mensaje);
                    $('#enviar').removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Añade un botón de submit al formulario y añade el evento a submit. Asi podemos aprovechar la validación del formulario de HTML.

```
$.ready(() => {

    $('#formulario').on('submit', submit); // Evita que se envie el formulario


    function submit (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajaxSetup({
            header:$('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        });

        $('#enviar').attr("disabled","disabled");
        var url = 'gerencia.crear';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $('#formulario').serialize(),
            dataType:'html',

            success: function (data) {
                var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if ((obj.estado=='ok')){
                    alert(obj.mensaje);
                    window.location="{{ route('gerencia_inicio') }}"

                } else{
                    alert(obj.mensaje);
                    $('#enviar').removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Si al hacerlo de esta manera te sigue saltando el error de "MethodNotAllowed". Entonces esta mal definida la ruta en Laravel. Asegurate de tener la ruta declarada en "routes/web.php" de la siguiente manera: `Route::post('gerencia.crear', 'llamada al controlador y metodo')`. Aunque no estoy seguro de si es posible utilizar rutas que contengan puntos.